# override y axis tick labels without affecting the graph shape in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

what I want to manually override the y axis tick labels without affecting the original plot.
For example, how I can show y axis tick labels [1,10,100,1000,10000] instead without affecting the original plot shape, i.e, still show a perfect quadratic curve.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
pl.plot(x, y)
pl.title(’Plot of y vs. x’)
pl.xlabel(’x axis’)
pl.ylabel(’y axis’)
pl.show()
```

I tried the following and it does not work

```
newYlabel = ['1','10','100','1000','10000']
p1.set_yticklabels(newYlabel)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`set_yticklabels` is the method of `Axes` instance, and is not present in the `pylab` interface. Try instead

```
pl.gca().set_yticklabels(newYlabel)
```

`gca` here stands for *get current axes*.

**EDIT**:
The picture:
[image]

The script that was used to obtain it:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
pl.plot(x, y)
pl.title('Plot of y vs. x')
pl.xlabel('x axis')
pl.ylabel('y axis')
newYlabel = ['1','10','100','1000','10000']
pl.gca().set_yticklabels(newYlabel)
pl.show()
```

Used matplotlib 1.4.3 with python 2.7.8 on Fedora 21.

Comment: it affects the shape of graph.  If you run your command, the curve is no longer in the graph.

Comment: That's strange. Did you change the tick positions as well? I edited the answer to add the picture.

Comment: I got a total blank figure without the curve. The x & y axis ticks are updated and being there. I am using newest Python Anaconda spider IDE with default setting, it might be the issue due to IDE?

Comment: You could get blank figure if you somehow changed graph limits - then the graph would scale down to almost a point. Changing tick labels should not affect tick positions, though. You can verify that the y-axis limits are not changed by issuing `pl.gca().get_ylim()` before `pl.show()` (you should get `(0.0, 25.0)`). 
It doesn't seem to be the issue in IDE; it's more like a matplotlib issue. I added my matplotlib version; I also added the script used to get the figure in case there's some stupid mistake somewhere in your script.