# Force python axis to show specific numbers

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a python plot, using the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(an_image)
```

What I want to do, is simply force the x and y axes, to span a certain minimum and maximum number. (Cannot do this with `ax.set_xlim()` or `ax.set_ylim()` because those *actually* change the axis limits). I just want some particular x_min , x_max , y_min, and y_max numbers to show up on my image.

How do I do that?

EDIT: To further clarify what I mean, look at this image below. What I *want*, are the numbers on the axes written in red. I want them to replace what is already there in black.  How do I accomplish that?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to manually change the ticks?

Comment: @GWW Ok, that is not what I am after, afterall.

Comment: Can you provide an example image?

Comment: @GWW I edited the question, with an actual image. Does it make sense now? I want to set my own "limits", shown in red, as well as specify their frequency. eg, -30, -20, -10, ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568516/override-y-axis-tick-labels-without-affecting-the-graph-shape-in-pyplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specifically set tick locations with:

```
ax.set_xticks([0, 200])
ax.set_yticks([0, 100])

ax.set_xticklabels(['-30', '+100'])
ax.set_yticklabels(['+20', '-20'])
```

Alternatively, you could change the origin to lower with `imshow` and you wouldn't have to flip the yticklabels.

Comment: Hmm, ok but when I go that, they all seem to be smooshed to the side. Does that make sense? So let's say I have an image that spans 100x200. I literally just want say, the xaxis to show it spanning from say, -54 to 453, for example, at some interval that I specify. Does that make sense?

Comment: '['-30', '+100']' is a list of strings. How then do I make a list of numbers, into a list of strings? I want to use the np.arange(...).tolist() command , but it seems that I need to then make that list into a list of strings. How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: I believe you can give `set_xticklabels` integers. I used strings so that the `+` is retained on the axes.  If you can't you can always use `map(str, NP.arange(...).tolist())`. You can do other fancy things with map if you need to specifically format the integers.  For example, `map('{0:+d}'.format, NP.arange(..))` will prepend `+` or `-` to the values.

Comment: This solution still doesn't work. It just "maxes out" at the first two numbers.

Comment: For example, saying `ax.set_xticklabels(['-10', '10', '30'])` just shows -10 and 10, and doesnt show 30 anywhere.

Comment: `set_xticks` sets the position, while `set_xticklabels` sets the text that appears at that position. So you need to have an additional `xtick` to go with the extra label

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using the image `extent` to set the actual scale of the image. 
I.e. to let your image scale from `-30`to `100` in x- and `-20` to `20` you can use

```
ax.imshow(data, origin="lower", extent=[-30, 100, -20,20])
```

An example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(size=(10,20))
xmin, xmax = -30, 100
ymin, ymax = -20, 20


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

extent= [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
ax.imshow(data, origin="lower", extent=extent)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin,xmax+1,10))
ax.set_yticks([-20,0,20])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this might scale the image pixels to be non-square. To preserve square pixels, you may use the `aspect` argument.

```
extent= [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
aspect=data.shape[0]/float(ymax-ymin)/(data.shape[1]/float(xmax-xmin))
ax.imshow(data, origin="lower", extent=extent, aspect=aspect)
```

[image]

You might also want to look at this question: [Matplotlib: how to make imshow read x,y coordinates from other numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260491/matplotlib-how-to-make-imshow-read-x-y-coordinates-from-other-numpy-arrays) for how to put the ticks to the pixel centers, which makes sense depending on the actual meaning of the data.